# How to feed a pair of vectors to a Classifier to classify similar/not similar

Tags: machine-learning, svm, logistic-regression, similarity, doc2vec

I am trying to Classify Document Vector pairs (Doc2Vec, 300 Features per Document) as similar/not similar. I tried Distance Messures (Cosine etc.) with additional Features like document size etc. but did not achieve perfect results, especially because I suspect, that only some of the features are meaningful for my problem.

What is the simple, but effective way to feed two vectors to a Classifier (LogisticRegression, SVM etc.)

- I already tested the subtraction of one vector from the other and use the absolute result as feature vector: `abs(vec1 -vec2)` but this was worse than distance messures
- I also tried the concatenation of both vectors, also with worse results. I suspect the doubling of dimension will increase the need of training samples, at least for some classifiers?

Is there a state-of-the-art way to classify similaritys or relationships between feature vectors? Or if there are concurent methods, which one is to prefer for which problem/classifier?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'd aim for your vectorization of the documents (eg via `Doc2Vec`) to give vectors where the similarities between vectors are a useful continuous similarity measure. (Most often this is cosine-similarity, but in some cases euclidean-distance may be worth trying as well.)

If the vectors coming out of the `Doc2Vec` stage don't  already exhibit that, the first thing to do would be to debug and optimize that process. That could involve:

- double-checking everything, including logged output of the process, for errors
- tweaking document preprocessing, to perhaps ensure salient document features are retained and noise discarded
- tuning `Doc2Vec` meta-parameters and modes, to ensure the resulting vectors are sensitive to the kinds of similarity that are important in your end-goals.

It'd be hard to say more about improving that step without more details about your data size and character, `Doc2Vec` choices/code so far, and end-goals.

How are *you* deciding whether two documents are "similar enough" or not? How much such evaluative data do you have to help score different `Doc2Vec` models in a repeatable, quantitative way. (Being able to do such automated scoring will let you test far more `Doc2Vec` permutations.) Are there examples of doc pairs where simple doc-vector cosine-similarity is working well, or not working well?

I see two red flags in the word you've chosen so far:

- "did not achieve perfect results" - getting "perfect" results is an unrealistic goal. You want to find something close to the state of the art, given the resources & tolerance-for-complexity of your project
- "300 Features per Document" - `Doc2Vec` doesn't really find "300 Features" that are independent. It's a single 300-dimensional "dense" "embedded" vector. Every direction – not just the 300 axes – may be meaningful. So even if certain "directions" are more significant for your needs, they're unlikely to be fully correlated with exact dimension axes.

It's possible a classifier on the `(v1 - v2)` difference, or `(v1 || v2)` concatenation, could help refine a "similar enough or not" decision, but you'd need a lot of training data, and perhaps a very sophisticated classifier.